# Tabela mestre detalhe, campos totalizadores

Tags: mysql, delphi, mariadb

Estou fazendo um controle de ordem de serviço onde em uma ordem de serviço vários usuários irão cadastrar produtos e mão de obra, sendo assim possuo três tabelas:
- Ordem de serviço (mestre)
- Produtos (detalhe)
- Mão de obra (detalhe)
As tabelas detalhes geram valores que terão que representar um total na tabela mestre, por exemplo um valor total de produtos e um valor total de mão de obra.
Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de obter este valor total se é usando recurso de consulta do banco de dados ou é melhor fazer um loop usando programação nas tabelas detalhes, lembrando que o sistema será multiusuário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanto faz, na verdade, você pode obter esta soma com um `SUM` e trazer os dados já mastigados para a aplicação, isso ganha um pouco na performance e na facilidade de programar, visto que a complexidade para gerar este cálculo no banco é realmente muito menor e você não tem que adicionar a complexidade lógica da iteração na sua aplicação, ela se torna literalmente um processador apenas.

Eu votaria pelo banco.